# Getting SIP headers through Asterisk manager

Tags: java, asterisk, sip

I am trying to elaborate SIP messages coming to an Asterisk server and edit them on the fly using Java.

AMI is supposed to work fine with that. Although I can't send any SIP messages though the socket, cause every-time I tried to edit chan_sip.c the server breaks down. So I haven't find a way to access this information from other classes of the manager. I don't want to save those information to a file or database cause this will delay the whole process.

Using Kamailio is not an option cause I want to make a comparison of both solutions so I need Asterisk.

Is there any path I should follow to get this done? I can't figure why editing chan_sip.c bothers Asterisk making him nonfunctional..

Comment: "Using Kamailio is not an option cause I want to make a comparison of both solutions so I need Asterisk." - Kamailio and Asterisk are not competitors in a SIP architecture, but complementary. They serve different purposes - one as a SIP proxy, the other as a B2BUA/media application server.

Answer (score 0):

Seams like no way with your qualification. Task seams really complex for me(i have more then 10 years experience, including asteirsk internal and c/c++ programming).Try do that using dialplan only

Comment: I saw your comment on a similar question and I wished you would answer, knowing that you may help.. Thanks for the answer..Can you please provide more info about achieving that using dialplan? You would be a savior....Although saying "Seams like no way with your qualification" already made this a challenge for me..

Comment: SIPHeader/SIPADDHeader functions in dialplan can manipulate with some headers. Some other headers will be directly converted to dialplan. I am sorry, i can recommend you read some book about asterisk. You have try do at least something acordinly to SO guideline. So no, nobody can help you. You need more knowledge to understand answer.